# How to convert this string manipulation function UTF-8 Compatible in PHP?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, diacritics

I had trouble finding a function that does exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunatly, this function isn't UTF-8 compatible. This functions is like a basic `ucwords` but it also does the uppercase on a character followed by one of the given characters found (in my case I need to apply an uppercase on the character found after a `-`).

Here is the function:

```
<?php
function my_ucwords($string)
  {
    $noletters='"([/-'; //add more if u need to
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($noletters); $i++)
      $string = str_replace($noletters[$i], $noletters[$i].' ', $string);
    $string=ucwords($string);
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($noletters); $i++)
      $string = str_replace($noletters[$i].' ', $noletters[$i], $string);
    return $string;
  }

$title = 'ELVIS "THE KING" PRESLEY - (LET ME BE YOUR) TEDDY BEAR';
echo my_ucwords(strtolower($title));
?>
```

As soon as I add accents to my string, e.g.:

```
echo my_ucwords(strtolower( "saint-étienne" )) //return: Saint- instead of Saint-Étienne
```

Any idea? I know instead of the `strlen` I could use `mb_strlen`. But what about the others?

**Edit:**
Just a reminder that I do not only need a simple `ucwords` working in `UTF-8`. I need it to apply the uppercase on any character found after a `-`.

I'm still trying to figure it out by myself, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is ucwords. A quick search on the php page made me discover this:

```
function mb_ucwords($str) {
    return mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
}
```

I tested and it works perfectly just remember this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: When I try your function echo mb_ucwords("saint-étienne") I get Saint-Tienne... I want a function that will return Saint-Étienne

Comment: Oops!... its working if I do echo mb_ucwords( utf8_encode("saint-étienne") ); Thank you sir!

Comment: @Cybrix if you need to encode the string there's something wrong with the charset of the page, always rememeber to add the meta tag on the webpage!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd need to swap a few functions.  First, there is no `str_replace` alternative for UTF-8 (you may or may not need it).  You should replace `ucwords` with [`mb_convert_case`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) and `strlen` with `mb_strlen`...

But there are more efficient ways to do it than looping several times:

```
function my_ucwords($string) {
    $chrs = '"([/-';
    $searchRegex = '/('.preg_quote($chrs, '/').')/u';
    $replaceRegex = '/('.preg_quote($chrs, '/').')\s/u';
    $tmpString = preg_replace($searchRegex, '\1 ', $string);
    $tmpString = mb_convert_case($tmpString, MB_CASE_TITLE);
    return preg_replace($replaceRegex, '\1', $tmpString);
}
```

Comment: Doh! I get a Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '-'

Comment: @Cybrix: fixed it in the code.  I forgot that `preg_quote` doesn't have a default delimiter (I thought it defaulted to `/`, but I was wrong)...

Comment: Yep working but now I get 'Saint-éTienne' when using: 'echo my_ucwords( utf8_encode("saint-étienne") );'

Comment: I now get `Saint-éTienne` when I run `echo my_ucwords( utf8_encode("saint-étienne") );`

Comment: Why are you using `utf8_encode`?  It doesn't do what you think it does...  Just run the raw through (or at worst case, use `mb_convert_encoding`, but `utf8_encode` doesn't work like that)...